# How to rewrite url on apache for specific path parameter

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to do URL rewriting with mod_rewrite like this :

```
example.com/path/foo/rest_of_path-> example.com/path/rest_of_path (remove foo)
example.com/path/bar/rest_of_path-> example.com/path/rest_of_path (remove bar)
example.com/path/sample/rest_of_path-> no rewriting<br/>
example.com/path/test/rest_of_path-> no rewriting
```

*foo*, *bar* are dynamic
*test*, *sample* are static, I have the list of path.

So I'm thinking of doing like this (in my httpd.conf):

```
RewriteCond ....... #it's here i'm blocking, how write only if $1 in test,sample ? 
RewriteRule  ^path/(.\*)/(.*)$  /path/$2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# You can add as much RewriteCond as you need to exclude static words
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/path/sample/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/path/test/.*
RewriteRule ^path/(.*)/(.*)  /path/$2
```

Comment: Thank you,
but it miss [OR] flag :

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/path/sample/.* [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/path/test/.*

Comment: No, you don't need [OR] but AND (which is implicit). You want the RewriteRule to apply only if there is no static word sample AND no static word test in the path. Or do I misunderstood you ?